# Finding the first year when the value wasn't the same as the latest year

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a table with data based on years (columns) and players (rows). I’m trying to find out for each player the first occurrence of when the data value in the latest year didn't match a previous year's value, and fill a cell with the year that change occurred.

```
         2011  2012 2013    2014    2015    2016
Player 1    -   -   10.0    10.0    10.0    10.0
Player 2    -   -   16.0    10.0    10.0    10.0
Player 3    -   -   16.0    10.0    20.0    10.0
```

The table above would populate another table by placing the year in the last column

- Player 1 is *2012*
- Player 2 is *2013*
- Player 3 is *2015*

I’ve searched and found a post that is similar: [Return the column number of the 2nd match](https://superuser.com/questions/992557/excel-help-is-it-possible-to-return-the-column-number-of-the-2nd-match-within/992671#992671). However I'm failing miserably to turn it into something that suits my table.

Many thanks for any pointers you can give.

Michael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your data in A1:G4, I was able to use the following formula:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$G$1, MATCH(2, 1/(B2:G2 <> G2), 1))
```

This is an array formula, so you have to use it with ctrl+shift+enter, instead of just enter.

It basically works by finding the array position of the last occurrence of whatever is *different* than the value in 2016, and then returning the header in the same array position.

Take player 3 as an example. It looks in the 2011-2016 array to see what is different than the 2016 value. Then, it makes a boolean array out of the comparisons. You generate the array [TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE], then make each value the divisor from 1. This results in a new array of [1, 1, 1, #DIV0, 1, #DIV0]. Then, you look to find the value 2 in the array. You cannot find it, but your match parameter is 1, i.e. return the last value less than or equal to the lookup value.

Here's a picture.

[image]

Comment: This has worked brilliantly! Thanks for the clear explanation as well. Thanks ever so much.